# C# делегаты и анонимные функции

Tags: c#, делегаты, анонимная-функция

Имеется следующий блок кода :

```
delegate int StrMod(int a);
static void main()
{
StrMod strmod = delegate{return 10;};
Console.WriteLine(strmod(5));
}
```

Консоль:

> 10

Почему на 4 строку компилятор не ругается? Ведь входные параметры анонимной функции не соответствуют параметрам делегата.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы здесь объявляете делегат с помощью анонимного метода.

```
StrMod strmod = delegate{return 10;};
```

Согласно документации об [анонимных методах](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods), у анонимного метода допускается опускать список параметров, если они вам не нужны внутри метода(в отличии от лямбд выражений, где список параметров нужно указывать всегда явно). В этом случае, анонимный метод может быть преобразован к делегату с различной сигнатурой.

> Anonymous methods enable you to omit the parameter list. This means
>   that an anonymous method can be converted to delegates with a variety
>   of signatures.

Поэтому этот код компилируется успешно.